# Swapping value in Map

Tags: java

There are two maps: Master Map and Modified Map.

```
if modifiedmap.key == mastermap.key
then set mastermap.value = modifiedmap.value
```

Here is what doing right now

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : modified_map.entrySet()) 
{
    for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry1:master_map.entrySet())
    {
        if(entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(entry1.getKey()))
        {
            entry1.setValue(entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

I am using two nested loops.
How ever map has a method called `containsKey()`
so I was try to use `master_map.containsKey()modified_map)` then assign the value

however i am not getting how to get `mastermap` Value corresponding to the matching key while trying to do with a single loop

something like this

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : modified_map.entrySet()) 
{
    if(master_map.containsKey(entry.getKey()))
    then get the corresponding value then swap it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need something like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : modified_map.entrySet()) {
  if (master_map.containsKey(entry.getKey())
    master_map.put (entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
}
```

This would modify the value of each entry in `master_map` that has a key that appears in `modified_map`.

> V put(K key,
>       V value)
>
> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map
>   (optional operation). **If the map previously contained a mapping for
>   the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value**. (A map m is
>   said to contain a mapping for a key k if and only if m.containsKey(k)
>   would return true.)